# Update all nested array records if a field does not exist in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the object below. 
"questions" is the document name and each question has a nested array of type answers property where some answers has a propoerty call status.

```
questions = [
{
    "_id": "idq1"
    "author" :"auth1"
    "Answers": []
},
{
    "_id": "idq2"
    "author" :"auth2"
    "Answers": [
        {
            "author": "auth1",
            "comments" [...],
            "status" : "1"
        },
        {
            "author": "auth2",
            "comments" [...],
        },
        {
            "author": "auth3",
            "comments" [...],
            "status" : "0"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I need to update all the nested Answers.status = "1" , where the Answers length > 0 and the nested element "status" does not exist. 
so the result would be :

```
questions = [
{
    "_id": "idq1"
    "author" :"auth1"
    "Answers": []
},
{
    "_id": "idq2"
    "author" :"auth2"
    "Answers": [
        {
            "author": "auth1",
            "comments" [...],
            "status" : "1"
        },
        {
            "author": "auth2",
            "comments" [...],
                "status" : "1"
        },
        {
            "author": "auth3",
            "comments" [...],
            "status" : "0"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Is "questions" also a field? Can you add the proper sample document?

Comment: questions is the document name and each question has a nested answers property where each answers has a status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My latest working code :

```
questions.updateMany(
            {
                "Answers.status" :null
            },
            { $set: { "Answers.$[i].status": 1 } },
            { new: true,
                arrayFilters: [{ "i.status": null}]        
            });
```

Comment: But this will not be able to update the "status" field if the "status" is not present in two or more documents of the same "Answers" array. If that's not the use case then it's okay :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `arrayFilters` for updating the array fields

Here I'm adding the query to update the document as required:

I have used the `multi: true` along with the `arrayFilter` to update multiple documents.

```
db.questions.update(
  {
    "Answers":{
      $nin:[
        [],
        null
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set:{
      "Answers.$[ans].status":"1"
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters:[
      {
        "ans.status":{
          $exists:false
        }
      }
    ],
    multi:true
  }
)
```

**Sample output**

```
{
    "_id": "idq1"
    "author" :"auth1"
    "Answers": []
},
{
    "_id": "idq2"
    "author" :"auth2"
    "Answers": [
        {
            "author": "auth1",
            "comments": [...],
            "status" : "1"
        },
        {
            "author": "auth2",
            "comments": [...],
            "status" : "1"
        },
        {
            "author": "auth3",
            "comments": [...],
            "status" : "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

For more about `arrayFilters` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Instead of `$nin`. best to use  `{ "Answers.1" : {$exists : true} }`

Comment: thanks @nayakam, that was helpful. Added to my knowledge :)